# Insert Json data into temp table using SQL Server Json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I try to insert below json in temp table,

```
{
  "offers": {
    "burstableenablement": {
      "prices": {
        "australia-central": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        },
        "australia-central-2": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        }
      }
    },
    "burstable-enablement1": {
      "prices": {
        "australia-central": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        },
        "australia-central-2": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        }
      }
    },
    "burstable-enablement2": {
      "prices": {
        "australia-central": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        },
        "australia-central-2": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Table:
the table should be like

```
burstableenablement   | australia-central   | 35.635 | WebDirect
burstableenablement   | australia-central-2 | 35.635 | WebDirect
burstable-enablement1 | australia-central   | 35.635 | WebDirect
burstable-enablement1 | australia-central-2 | 35.635 | WebDirect
```

the above table show like in temp, i don't know how to achieve that, any solution it helpful for me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out OPENJSON, it should be able to convert data from json to table form

Comment: Hi @siggemannen, actually it contain dynamic keys like burstableenablement, burstable-enablement1, i don't know how to process it with OPENJSON

Comment: You can use "edged" version of OPENJSON (this is the version where you dont declare columns) to get the dynamic key data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
select x.[key], y.[key], json_value(y.value, '$.value') AS value, json_value(y.value, '$.pricingType')
from openjson(N'{
  "offers": {
    "burstableenablement": {
      "prices": {
        "australia-central": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        },
        "australia-central-2": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        }
      }
    },
    "burstable-enablement1": {
      "prices": {
        "australia-central": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        },
        "australia-central-2": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        }
      }
    },
    "burstable-enablement2": {
      "prices": {
        "australia-central": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        },
        "australia-central-2": {
          "value": 35.635,
          "pricingType": "WebDirect"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}', '$.offers') x
cross apply openjson(value, '$.prices') y
```

Comment: `cross apply openjson(y.value) with (value decimal(18,9), pricingType varchar(30)) z` is probably easier and faster.

Comment: @siggemannen, thanks now its working as expected

Comment: @harishk, yeah, check out charlieface's improvement too